# Find Last occurrence index value of outer list in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hey i have nested list and i wanted to find last occurrence index value of outer list. I tried to search in [Kotlin Doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of-last.html). I tried some code but I failed. So how can I do this in my case in efficient way.

```
fun main() {
    val value = listOf(
        Group(0, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "1"))),
        Group(1, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "2"))),
        Group(2, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "3"))),
        Group(3, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "4"))),
        Group(4, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "5"))),
        Group(5, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "6"))),
        Group(6, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "6"), GroupValue(false, "7"))),
        Group(7, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "6"), GroupValue(false, "7"))),
        Group(8, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "6"), GroupValue(true, "7"), GroupValue(false, "7"))),
        Group(9, mutableListOf(GroupValue(false, "6"), GroupValue(true, "7"))),
        Group(10, mutableListOf(GroupValue(true, "7")))
    )

    val result = value.asSequence().flatMap { it.value }.indexOfLast { conversationItems ->
        conversationItems?.isRead == false
    }
    println("result $result")

}
```

**Group**

```
data class Group(
    val key: Int,
    val value: MutableList<GroupValue?>
)
```

**GroupValue**

```
data class GroupValue(
    val isRead: Boolean? = null,
    val id: String? = null
)
```

**Getting output of above code is**

```
result 13
```

**Expected Output**

```
result 9
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong in above logic

Comment: I suggest making `isRead` non-nullable if you don't need null values. It would make your code easier to work with.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I can’t do `isRead ` non-nullable, because object is coming different type from server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

13 is correct since you used `flatMap`, which turns all your lists into a single list and you're getting the index of an item in that bigger, combined list.

From what you said you expected, I'm guessing you want the index of the outer list for the last Group containing a `false` `isRead` GroupValue. I would do that like this:

```
val result = value.indexOfLast { group ->
    group.value.any { it?.isRead == false }
}
```

Comment: thanks again for helping me. What is the use of `any` ?

Comment: `any` returns true if the condition in the lambda passes for any item in the collection. We don't care which specific item of the inner list has a `false` `isRead` since you only want the index from the outer list.

Comment: thanks @Tenfour04 great answer